# PECL Extensions for Windows

Tags: php, windows, pecl

Where can I download extensions from PECL for PHP 5.3? I find that the links are only for 5.2.6, and the site of PECL4Win is discontinued.

I tried to download extensions from PECL on the site but the code is written in C and I can not compile the files and get the .dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you compile the C files? There is a lot of tutorials out there that show you how to do it. It takes an hour or two to get all configured and setup, but it's worth it because you don't need to wait in the future for new .dll files to come out, you can just compile yourself.

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

On php it says:

**PECL extensions for Windows is being worked on. The interface on the pecl website will most likely be updated to offer Windows DLL download right from that website.
In the meantime, some extensions can be found here.**

http://pecl.php.net/